# Facebook Ads API: how does offline_access work?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

If you have a preferred developer app with access to Ads API you can ask for the offline_access permission, according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/)

How does it work? When I obtain the token, I get something like:

```
access_token=hehehehehe&expires=5183795
```

.. which would mean that the token expires in two months as usually. Will it be extended automatically? Or do I have to do some additional action to get the non-expiring token?

Comment: Facebook has depreciated the `offline_access` permission.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena: with a few exceptions, including Ads API: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 0):

After some time, I finally found an answer. If you have a whitelisted app, you'll don't get the expired field in the response:

```
access_token=hehehehehe
```

This works for whitelisted apps whether you ask for `offline_access` or not.

Comment: by whitelist, do you mean Standard Access? With Basic do you still get an expires field?

Comment: @Sam a lot has changed since I posted this answer. Now there's the Basic and Standard Marketing App review, not sure how this is bound to offline access.